# Finding negation of a statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

> $p:$ Two lines have at most one intersection point . Then what is the negation of $p$

This question was asked in class , i said that the answer must be "Two lines have $\color{red}{\text{not}}$ at most one intersection point" .However, my proffesor said that my answer is wrong , but she did not say the true answer. What is the true answer , what am i missing ?

Comment: Well, first of all, "two lines have not at most one intersection point" is not grammatically correct, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean. Second, the interesting version of the question is to give the negation of $p$ *without* using words like "not"; otherwise, "It is not the case that $p$" is a universal solution.

Comment: Maybe it's  Two lines *can* have two or more intersection points

Comment: The negation of "all $A$ satisfy $B$" is not "no $A$ satisfies $B$."   The negation of "all people are at least $6$ feet tall" is not "there are no people who are at least $6$ feet tall."

Answer (score 1):

The statement is really a *universal* statement about *any* two lines.  That is, the original statement says that *any* two lines have at most one intersection point.

The negation of that would be: There exist (or: there can be) two lines with two or more intersection points

Comment: so can i conclude that if there is "at most" , then change it with "at least " , and if there is "at least" , then change it with "at most"

Comment: Well, it's not that simple: the negation of at most 1 is not at least 1 ... it would be more than 1 which, in the case of whole numbers, would be at least 2.   But the main thing I point out in my Answer is the fact that the original statement was a universal statement

Comment: what if it were the consequent part of an implication ? then it would not be an universal statement , right? So , let think it like consequent part of an implication , then what will happen ?

Comment: @webboo  I am not sure what kind of conditional you are thinking of ... but even if this was the consequent of a conditional, it would still be a universal. And, if you negate that conditional, you would get the conjunction of the antecedent together with the negation of the consequent, and so you would still need to work with the negation of this statement, i.e. you would still end up having to negate a universal